# Multicolumn and thead problem in tabularx

Tags: tables, lyx, tabularx

I am trying to implement a code using tabularx and multicolumn along with head, but I keep on getting an error. The code is as follows:

```
\begindocumnet{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{ >{\RaggedRight}X }
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\newcolumntype{Y}{ >{\Centering}X}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

\noindent 

\newcolumntype{Y}{ >{\Centering}X} 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} lYYY @{}}  

\toprule 


\thead[lc]{Category}   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Forecasting Horizon}}& 

& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{1 Period}} & {\multicolumn{2}{c}{1 Period}} & 

\multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{3 Period}}  \\


&  \thead{TSMOM (1,1)} & \thead{TSMOM (3,3)} 

& \thead{TSMOM (1,1)} & \thead{TSMOM (3,3)} & \thead{TSMOM (1,1)} 

& \thead{TSMOM (3,3)} \\

\midrule  

Test-Statistic & 0 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ \addlinespace

P-value & 0 & 0.59 & 1.00 \\ \addlinespace  

\bottomrule  

\end{tabularx}
```

To provide an idea, I basically want to make a chart with the following content

[image]

except I would like to have the layout in the following format :

[image]

However, I get the following error such as: "extra alignment tab has been change to \cr" could someone please help advise me where I am making a mistake with the code ? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mismatch in MWE (one `multicolum` is probably accidentally  repeated). Corrected (and slightly improved) code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{booktabs,makecell,multirow,tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}

\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
    \usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage{siunitx}

    \usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{6}{C} @{}}
    \toprule
\thead{Forecasting Horizon}
    &   \mc{\thead{1 Period}}
        &   \mc{\thead{2 Period}}
            &   \mc{\thead{3 Period}}               \\
    \cmidrule(rl){2-3}\cmidrule(rl){4-5}\cmidrule(rl){6-7}
\thead{strategies}
    &  \thead{TSMOM\\ (1,1)}
        &   \thead{TSMOM\\ (3,3)}
            &   \thead{TSMOM\\ (1,1)}
                &   \thead{TSMOM\\ (3,3)}
                    &   \thead{TSMOM\\ (1,1)}
                        &   \thead{TSMOM\\ (3,3)}   \\
    \midrule
Test-Statistic
    & \mc{0} & \mc{1.00} & \mc{1.00}                \\ 
    %\addlinespace
P-value & \mc{0} & \mc{0.59} & \mc{1.00}            \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much ! Would you mind explaining whether it is necessary for me to use the geometry package for "\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}" ? I seem to be getting an error saying that there is an "option clash for package geometry" (I am using lyx but am not sure if this is specific to lyx). Any how, could I get rid of this package because when I wipe out the preamble, I seem to be getting an error that says "undefined control sequence". Sorry for nothing you again but I tried looking via other sources without success and was hoping that you could give me some advice

Comment: @TheStudent, you didn't provide any information about your document, so I use geometry for determining page layout. My solution works also without it. Unfortunately, i newer use Lyx, so I haven't any clue, how/where the page layout is defined in it.

Comment: Ah, I had found out where I made an error and yes, you are correct about the code not working without the geometry package. Thank you very much for your help again :)